# change image instantly if i enter any input in text box with out using button action

Tags: ios7, uiimageview

```
I have tried the bellow code-

  -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {
        if (self.textfield.text.length!=0)
           { 
           self.image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Free-Boiler-Circle.png"];
           }
        else
           {
            self.image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"GREY_CIRCLE.png"];
           }       
    }
```

But when i tried this it change image when i go to the next field after entering value the previous field it change image.... but i want to do when i entering any single text in text field it will change image instantly.
please help me. thnx in advnce.

Comment: What has xcode have to do with this code or what you are trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to change image instantly when user enter any text.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode itself, which is the IDE. You code is about the iOS SDK, more specifically image views.

Comment: in android there is text watcher i want to know what is in ios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

Either implement `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` and in there do your logic, or begin listening to `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` notifications by registering in `viewDidLoad`, like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textDidChange:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:self.textfield];
```

This will be called every time your text field changes:

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if (self.textfield.text.length!=0)
    { 
        self.image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Free-Boiler-Circle.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        self.image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"GREY_CIRCLE.png"];
    }   
}
```

Don't forget to call `removeObserver:` in your view controller's `dealloc`.